# Conversion of JSON object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am running a database query in php controller and returning the result to an Ajax function. Here's the php code.

```
public function trackUnreadMsgs(){
        $data['userData']  = $this->session->userdata('userData');
        $user_id           = $data['userData'][0]['id'];
        $QueryResult = $this->data->myquery("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE `to`=" . $user_id . " AND status='unread'");
        $QueryResult = json_encode($QueryResult);
        print_r($QueryResult);
}
```

Here's my function in ajax:

```
var colourNewMessage = urlToPass + '/home/trackUnreadMsgs';
$.ajax({
    url: colourNewMessage,
    context: document.body,
    success: function(result){
             console.log(result);
    }
});
```

My Question is that how can I convert the returned json object to javascript array.

Comment: This must be a duplicate. I saw this not the other day...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you please flag it then?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy doing so now... I'm looking for it

Comment: @evolutionbox Please help

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy please help, I'm in a tight situation

Comment: If you're expecting a json object as response from server then add `dataType: "json"` setting to your AJAX request.

Comment: Are you sure the returned data is a JSON object, not a JSON array? `json_encode` will create a JSON array if `$QueryResult` is a PHP array with numeric indexes, not an associative array.

Comment: If the JSON is surrounded with `[]` then it's an array, not an object. There should be no need to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a well formed JSON object say `json,` then all you need to do to convert it to JavaScript object is to use

```
var jsobj = JSON.parse(json)
```